# jQueryでプラグインを使わずにスクロールの速度を変更するにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQueryでプラグインを使わずにスクロールの速度を変更するにはどうすればいいですか？

メソッドやプロパティなどありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どの動作をした時のスクロールの速度のコントロールをしたいのかわかりませんが、

jQueryのAnimate関数を利用することでスクロールの速度は変更できます。
[.animate() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
scrollTopやscrollLeftなどの非スタイルプロパティやカスタムプロパティもアニメーションできます。

あとはイベント発火時に通常のスクロールイベントを打ち消して上記のイベントに置き換えれば実施できるともいます

```js
$(function(){

  $("#toTop").click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<div style="height:500px;">↓↓↓↓↓</div>
<button id="toTop">上へ</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: マウスホイールを回した時のスクロールのスピードです。

Comment: その際もscrollイベントを使って、上の方法でできるかもしれませんね。ありがとうございます！

Comment: マウスホイールを回したときであれば、onwheelイベント検知して、デフォルトの効果を消して、このイベントに変更するという方法でしょうかね。もしわからなければ質問してください

Comment: なるほど、そうすればいいんですね！ありがとうございます！